# Is this javascript frontend, NodeJS backend scenario viable to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain

I have a Domain-A which is static site built on netlify to provide shopping cart facilities.

I have a Domain-B server backend running a payment on Node.JS, and processing Auth Services via passport.js.

As a static site on Netlify this Domain-A cannot provide any backend services. The user sees this domain's web pages, selects products, and eventually presses a buy button. This button invokes JS code running in the browser, sending an AJAX /login to Domain-B. It successfully logs in. It returns a connect.sid cookie to Domain-A with SameSite:none, Secure:true. I can see the cookie with Chrome Debugger.

After a successful login return from Domain-B, Domain-A now sends an AJAX GET to Domain-B requesting seller and payment information. But the GET always fails with a 403 "User Not Logged In".

The AJAX GET includes

```
crossDomain: true,
headers: { 
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    "withCredentials": true
},
```

The Content-Type is to make it a CORS Simple Get and avoid Preflight issues, the withCredentials to make sure the cookie is included with the GET. I tried using a POST but it seems to always trigger Preflight processing which creates a lot of other complexities.

My basic question is, should I be able to do this, login and perform a GET from browser code of the Domain-A static site, to a NodeJS server on Domain-B? OR, must I get off Netlify and put it onto something like DigitalOcean where Domain-A has a backend which can login and get or post to Domain-B?

Is there sample code somewhere where I can copy the structure to my scenario?

UPDATE: 2022-02-20
This is my server side cors() code:

```
var corsOptions = {
  "origin": 'https://www.chicagomegashop.com',
  "methods": "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS",
  "credentials": true,
  "allowedHeaders": ['Content-Type'],
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Regarding my concern that no cookie is being saved. Here is the cookie as it arrives as a Response Header:
[image]

[image]

But now, when checking for the cookie at the domain, it is not there:

[image]

IS something wrong or am I not interpreting what I see correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try moving `withCredentials` outside of `headers`

```
crossDomain: true,
headers: { 
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
},
withCredentials: true
```

Also, on your backend server, do you have cors configured to allow what your frontend is trying to do?

```
 cors({
    origin: 'netlifysite_uri',
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
  })
```

Comment: knicholas thanks for your suggestions. I went dark because I went to the periodontist & all hell broke inside my mouth. I'm back, in pain, but back debugging. Moving withCredentials works but didn't change anything. Adding allowedHeaders in CORS() was a good call, something new, but no change.

Here's an observation- when I successfully do the login to passport.js, Chrome DevTools shows a set-cookie in the Response Headers, as I would expect. But when I look at cookies for the domain, there's no cookie. Of course then my subsequent POST comes back user undefined. Why was no cookie stored?

Comment: Note added code at the bottom of my original posting.